# Variables in Sqlite execution when being passed into a function (Python3)

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, sqlite

For a while I have been looking at how to read/write to a sqlite database from different threads, I found lots of answers and documents describing what needed to happen however I was nowhere near able to achieve what was needed so I decided to use an existing class I found made by someone else.

Ashamed to admit but figuring out how to get this class to work has taken a few hours despite me now not knowing why however I am unable to get variables inside of the execution function

I would normally do it like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT codeID FROM users WHERE codeID=:code", {'code':tag_attempt})
```

This worked fine however when I try the same thing with the multithread class it will not work (The class has a 'select' function which fetches and returns the data, which was the only way I have been able to fetch data from the database, however the execute function has the exact same issue) (I also tried this method of using variables)

```
for q in sql.select(("select codeID from users where codeID=?", (tag_attempt)), 0):
    print(q)
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This is the class used but I will also included the link

```
class MultiThreadOK(Thread):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(MultiThreadOK, self).__init__()
        self.db = db
        self.reqs = Queue()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        cnx = sqlite3.Connection(self.db)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        while True:
            req = self.reqs.get()
            if req == '--close--':
                break
            elif req == '--commit--':
                cnx.commit()
            try:
                cursor.executescript(
                    req) if ';' in req else cursor.execute(req)
            except sqlite3.OperationalError as err:
                self.escribir_error(
                    '{0} - Error {1}\n'.format(datetime.now(), err))
                self.escribir_error('{0} - {1}\n'.format(datetime.now(), req))
            except:
                self.escribir_error('{0} - Salida'.format(datetime.now()))
        cnx.close()

    def execute(self, req):
        self.reqs.put(req)

    def queries(self):
        return self.reqs.qsize()

    def empty(self):
        return self.reqs.empty()

    def select(self, req, results=0):
        cnx = sqlite3.Connection(self.db)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        try:
            if results == 0:
                cursor.execute(req)
                ret = [x for x in cursor.fetchall()]
                cnx.close()
                return ret
            else:
                cursor.execute(req)
                ret = [x for x in cursor.fetchall()[:results]]
                cnx.close()
                return ret
        except:
            print("Unexpected error: {0}".format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
            cnx.close()

    def commit(self):
        self.execute("--commit--")

    def close(self):
        self.execute('--close--')

    def escribir_error(self, texto):
        #with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\errores.txt', 'a') as archivo:
        #    archivo.write(texto)
        print(texto)
```

**Summary** I would like to be able to fetch data while in a separate thread which is possible with this class I have just not been able to include variables at any stage

**Credit** https://gist.github.com/User001501/3053f26100ddf281600668fed347e518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method execute receive a single parameter.

Looks like you can use the string named placeholders like

```
c.execute("SELECT codeID FROM users WHERE codeID='{code}'".format(**{'code': ag_attempt})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also found an answer and was typing it when you posted yours.  I will check to see if your suggestion works aswell

Comment: I changed the class back to the way that it was in the question and tried your method and it gave the same error as before, however I appreciate your answer and help

Comment: I modified the answer for the case that the code is a string, myy be that is your case. Anyway, this is not the proper way to manage parameters in sql because is unsafe.

Comment: Yes, I can see how it makes sense, I was happy when I saw it because it seemed more robust and variable.  When you say the proper way to manage parameters are you talking about it not being the standard method?  Not sure what unsafe means (I will test again with the string)

Comment: I'm pleased to say with the string change you made it now works as expected, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and would like to post it just in case it benefits anyone in the future

I passed a new argument which was just the dictionary into the functions in the class, I will comment on the changed lines.  This new code works with the lines I was trying to use in the question so the input to the function is the same and works like regular sqlite.

```
class MultiThreadOK(Thread):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(MultiThreadOK, self).__init__()
        self.db = db
        self.reqs = Queue()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        cnx = sqlite3.Connection(self.db)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        while True:
            req, arg, res = self.reqs.get() # Add arg and res here
            if req == '--close--':
                break
            elif req == '--commit--':
                cnx.commit()
            try:
                cursor.executescript(
                    req, arg) if ';' in req else cursor.execute(req, arg) # Add arg in two places
            except sqlite3.OperationalError as err:
                self.escribir_error(
                    '{0} - Error {1}\n'.format(datetime.now(), err))
                self.escribir_error('{0} - {1}\n'.format(datetime.now(), req))
            except:
                self.escribir_error('{0} - Salida'.format(datetime.now()))
        cnx.close()

    def execute(self, req, arg=None, res=None):
        self.reqs.put((req, arg or tuple(), res)) # Add this

    def queries(self):
        return self.reqs.qsize()

    def empty(self):
        return self.reqs.empty()

    def select(self, req, arg, results=0): # Add arg here
        cnx = sqlite3.Connection(self.db)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        try:
            if results == 0:
                cursor.execute(req, arg) # Add arg here
                ret = [x for x in cursor.fetchall()]
                cnx.close()
                return ret
            else:
                cursor.execute(req, arg) # Add arg here
                ret = [x for x in cursor.fetchall()[:results]]
                cnx.close()
                return ret
        except:
            print("Unexpected error: {0}".format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
            cnx.close()

    def commit(self):
        self.execute("--commit--")

    def close(self):
        self.execute('--close--')

    def escribir_error(self, texto):
        #with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\errores.txt', 'a') as archivo:
        #    archivo.write(texto)
        print(texto)
```

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution. You can make the `arg` parameter on the `select()` method  optional too.